# json_encode with log information placed in from of the real data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I use ajax to sent data (a form form html) to php, php would process the data and  return result from php to ajax again. I checked php did its job. And php also gets the right result.

```
$responseArray = array("type" => "success", "message" => $okMessage);

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {            
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8', true);           
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);             
    echo $encoded;
}
```

and the following code is really called,

But the data ajax received is

```
2017-10-05 23:18:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2017-10-05 23:18:04 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, bla...bla...
{"type":"success","message":"Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!"}
```

In this case I only need the last line. I tried to stop it to print the log information. One solution is to change /etc/php.ini. But I do not have this file.

Here is the .js code clip.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    //  dataType:"json", /*can not get data back from php but the output of php is right */
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        // we recieve the type of the message: success x danger and apply it to the 
        var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
        var messageText = data.message;

        // let's compose Bootstrap alert box HTML
        var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';

        $('#main-contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
        // empty the form
        $('#main-contact-form')[0].reset();
        // If we have messageAlert and messageText
        if (messageAlert && messageText) {
            // inject the alert to .messages div in our form
            $('#main-contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
            // empty the form
            $('#main-contact-form')[0].reset();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: at top of cb: `data=JSON.parse(data.trim().split("\n").pop())`

Comment: in some where in function you `echo data` that's why you receive , check your code again and remove `echo or print_r`.

Comment: @dandavis hello. Thanks for your comment! I tried it. It works! Could you please write it in the answer? And what is your opinion that where the log is introduced? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

**php file**

hide the header function (not mandatory) `//header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8', true);` the json encoded is correct.

```
$responseArray = array("type" => "success", "message" => $okMessage);

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {            

    //header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8', true);           
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);             
    echo $encoded;
}
```

**.js code**

datatype added json and used  data['type'] and data['message']

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
dataType:"json",
data: $(this).serialize(),
success: function(data) {
    // we recieve the type of the message: success x danger and apply it to the 
    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data['type'];
    var messageText = data['message'];

    // let's compose Bootstrap alert box HTML
    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';

    $('#main-contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
    // empty the form
    $('#main-contact-form')[0].reset();
    // If we have messageAlert and messageText
    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
        // inject the alert to .messages div in our form
        $('#main-contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
        // empty the form
        $('#main-contact-form')[0].reset();
    }
}
});
```

Note: I didnt tested the above code.

Comment: 1.Please put some information why you dont want to add header as json. 2. Json data cant accessible using data['value']. You have to use dot operator

Comment: data['type'] is wrong. data.type its correct way to access json data

Comment: @Devs, thanks for the answer. But it does not work.  data=JSON.parse(data.trim().split("\n").pop()) solved the problem.